# Websphere Application Server - EJB3 - MDB - using ListenerPort

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, message-driven-bean, websphere-8

Is it possible to bind (EJB 3.1) MDBs using ListenerPort (instead of activation specification) in websphere application server 8.0?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: i am migrating from EJB2.1 to EJB3.1 and I would like to use the existing way of binding, using Listener Ports.

Comment: i am not able to post code in the comments field.  it allows only 500 characters

Comment: I have put my code here http://pastie.org/private/qfiuxyk2paydwz1a2ct7g

Comment: What is the exact version of WAS 8 you are using 8.0.0.X ?

Comment: Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.0.0.0
ID                    BASE
Build Level           hh1108.14
Build Date            2/25/11
Architecture          x86 (32 bit)
Installed Features    EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are experiencing is due to a bug in WebSphere: [PM47459](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM47359)

Installing the latest fixpack will probably resolve the issue.

Comment: I think this will solve the issue.  I will install the fixpack and confirm.  for documentation purposes, the error was "com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: The MDBean message-driven bean (MDB) does not have a corresponding binding in the binding file."

Comment: Thanks Aviram.  Installing the WAS fixpack 8.0.0.4 solved the issue.